How to fix error: The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused when deploying to Minikube?
I am trying to deploy an app (angular) on minikube via gitlab-ci.yml. All the stages pass the pipeline without any issue. The last stage which is deploy keeps failing with the following error:

error: error validating "kubernetes/deployment.yaml": error validating data: failed to download openapi: Get "http://localhost:8080/openapi/v2?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Here is the gitlab-ci file:
stages:
  - install
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

include: 'ci/variables/default.yml'

install_dependencies:
  image: node:20.18.0-slim
  stage: install
  tags:
    - ci
  script:
    - npm config set registry ${CI_NPM_REGISTRY}
    - npm install
    - echo "Variables are '$CI_PROJECT_DIR' and '$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE'"
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 days
    when: on_success
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  before_script:
    - npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline

test_app:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - ci
  script:
    - npm run test-headless
    - echo "Unit Test Job" || export failure=1

build_app:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - build
  # Use the official docker image.
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
    - echo "folder before cd:"
        - ls
        - cd sinc-shop
        - "CHECK CHECK - '$CI_COMMIT_SHA'"
  script:
    # Docker: Builds a Docker image for the Angular app and pushes it to the GitLab Container Registry.
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
    - chmod +x ci/scripts/test-script.sh
    - ci/scripts/test-script.sh "VARIABLE_A" "VARIABLE_B"

  # Run this job where a Dockerfile exists
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
      exists:
        - Dockerfile

deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  image:
    name: bitnami/kubectl
    entrypoint: [""]
  
  script:
    - kubectl apply -f kubernetes/deployment.yaml
    - kubectl apply -f kubernetes/service.yaml

  environment:
    name: production
    url: http://localhost:8080
    kubernetes:
      namespace: default
  only:
    - main

The gitlab-agent for Kubernetes has also been set und is connected.
I have been searching in couple of online resources including Deploy applications on Minikube Doc. I believe that there are couple of questions here in SO which look similar to my issue. I checked them, but all the suggested solutions/hints didn't help. The issue just remains same! Any idea where I am going wrong please?
P.S: I have posted this question in SO. But I found out later that this would be the right place to post such questions.
